# Website to create data models and web services for iOS (or similar) online?

Tags: web-services, rest, ios5, restkit, entity-relationship

A few months ago I visited an interesting web site. It was a web to create data models (online) and web services (rest or soap) and deploy them at the moment, all without coding any server or SQL.
I think it's interesting for creating prototypes when I create iOS apps, as many of them are just web service consumers.
The problem is that I forgot the name of the website.
Do you know that website or similar services?
Thanks.

Comment: if possible, try scanning through your browser history . Or if you use google services, it might be in your google web history. https://history.google.com/history/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackmob is one such service that allows you to create models on their servers easily.

https://www.stackmob.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. I realized that's called BaaS (Backend) and there are a lot like stackmob or parse, among others. Thanks for suggestion to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably talking about https://parse.com/, they are really doing a great job, iterating really fast. I used them in the past and I would go with Parse anytime before Stackmob.

Comment: Thanks for reply. BTW, can I embed some logic (like triggers or stored procedures,or business logic) in those services?

Comment: Parse recently launched https://parse.com/products/cloud_code -- which looks interesing, haven't tried it yet.